# How to send a dictionary with jQuery ajax and Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I am trying to send a dictionary using jQuery and Python. The problem is if I use async: false it works, but my goal is to send the data with async: true.
Also, when I send the data the alert() I have in the "complete" function it's showing two times. How can I solve these two problems?

I attach the JavaScript code and Python code:

First the Javascript code:

```
arrObj = [['numero', 'dato', 'dato2'], ['12345', 'prueba', 'prueba2'], ['54321', 'abeurp', '2abeurp'], ['112233', 'trewq', 'fdsag']];
var n = arrObj.length;

for(var i=1;i<n;i++){

    var jsonArr = {};
    jsonArr = {'numero': arrObj[i][0],
        'dato': arrObj[i][1],
        'dato2': arrObj[i][2]
        };
    jsonArr = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);

    $.ajax({
        data: jsonArr,
        type: 'post',
        url: '/getData',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function(output){
            console.log('error');
        },
        success: function(output){
            console.log('bien ' + i);
        },
        complete: function(output){         
            alert("fin");
        }
    });
}
```

And the Python script:

```
class getData(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        v1 = self.request.get('numero')
        v2 = self.request.get('dato')
        v3 = self.request.get('dato2')

        logging.info('DEBUG: var1=' + v1 + ' var2=' + v2 + ' var3=' + v3)

        self.response.out.write('good')
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why do you need to make request synchronously? Have you verified that your server is receiving 4 requests? Hvae you inspected the requests through your javascript console?

Comment: It's synchronously because it has to be like that. I've resolved the problem by myself. It was the block of code from jsonArr = {'numero': arrObj[i][0]... And the stringify function. After I removed it, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code and it looks that the POST itself does arrive to the server.

Anyway, you say you get two "fin" alerts, but actually you should get four.

First, you lost one in the loop because you start counting from 1. So change the for loop to begin from 0.

Still, we need to find another one. Could it be that you refresh or redirect the page right after you run the ajax call? If you do, it could explain why it has not finished all the POSTs.

A simple solution for that might be counting the "fin"s and refreshing/redirecting only after all the arrObj.length counted. That would be also a better timing for displaying the "fin" alert.

A much better solution is rewriting your server side so it accepts your entire dictionary array, and then you can just send it like:

```
$.ajax({
data: arrObj,
...
```

and then, on the server side, parse the JSON and iterate over it.
That would be much nicer and more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've found the problem after I removed the three lines before the $.ajax function and write the dictionary like this: jsonArray['numero'] = element. The second problem I had I solved it too.